# Codeblocks succeeded in compiling, but gcc failes, Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I'm using ubuntu 18. 
I'v installed codeblocks ide and bare gnu gcc compiler (command line) both

**gcc version 7.4.0** (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

code blocks **16.01**

I wrote a very simple code to create and print a string variable

Code blocks(with inbuilt gnu gcc compiler) succeeded in compiling. But bare gcc compiler failes

I've tried by including iostream and stdio also

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "I am learning C++";
    printf("%s",a.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

codeblocks compiles it successfully and gives the output without raising an error. As well as sololearn online compiler also

**I am learning C++**

I got into the folder where the cpp file is and gave following command

**gcc string_var.cpp -o string_var.out**

Bt the bare gcc compiler gives some long stuff of compiler errors which i can't understand

```
/tmp/ccen8bfp.o: In function `main':
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
string_var.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/ccen8bfp.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If you use the printf() function, you need to add # include <cstdio> at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc string_var.cpp -o string_var.out
```

gcc is a C compiler. You want to compile C++ code:

```
g++ string_var.cpp -o string_var.out
```

It just so happens that either `gcc` or `g++` works insofar as compiling the actual code, the compiler understand that `.cpp` files contain C++ code, and proceeds accordingly.

However, when it times to linking the resulting object module, `gcc` does not provide the runtime C++ library to the linker (it still thinks it's just a C compiler, and has never heard of C++), resulting in your link failure.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) can be used to compile many different languages. Some of those languages are common enough that they can use the same front-end program.

C and C++ are two such languages, and both can be compiled with the `gcc` front-end program. However, the `gcc` program by default is for C code, and because of that don't use some flags needed to build C++ programs. One such missing thing is that `gcc` doesn't link with the C++ standard library.

You can solve this by explicitly linking with the library:

```
gcc string_var.cpp -o string_var.out -lstdc++
```

Or, even simpler, use the front-end program for C++, `g++`:

```
g++ string_var.cpp -o string_var.out
```